# Looking for title + author of old children's SF novel

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone help me out with the title of an old children's SF book involving an interdimensional whirlwind? Early '70's at the latest.

Comment: Can you give any more details? Cover art? Any other plot details? Not much to go on here.

Comment: Possibly A Wrinkle in Time, Madeleine l'Engle?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: Yes, far too broad. Even had *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz* been the first book with this theme (probably not), there were so many others, including outright derivatives, between when it was published and the 70s that this question has no unique answer.

Answer (score 16):

[The Wonderful Wizard of Oz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Wizard_of_Oz) by L. Frank Baum

> The story chronicles the adventures of a young farm girl named Dorothy in the magical Land of Oz, after she and her pet dog Toto are swept away from their Kansas home by a cyclone.
>
> Originally published on May 17, 1900. It has since been reprinted on numerous occasions, most often under the title **The Wizard of Oz**